# Better way to jump in and out a loop without goto?

Tags: c++, c, goto

```
do {
    int j, k;
    if (num_copy_array[0][0] == num_copy_array[0][1]) {
        goto next_num;
    } else {
        goto first_time;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_LEN; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < NUM_LEN; k++) {
            goto skip;
        first_time:
            j = 0, k = 2;
        skip:
            for (int j_2 = 0; j_2 <= j; j_2++) {
                for (int k_2 = 0; k_2 <= NUM_LEN; k_2++) {
                    if (j_2 == j && k_2 == k) {
                        goto next_digit;
                    }
                    if (num_copy_array[j][k] == num_copy_array[j_2][k_2]) {
                        goto next_num;
                    }
                }
            }
        next_digit:;
        }
    }
} while (false);
/*
 * some
 * code
*/
:next_num // starts the bigger loop outside
```

This is how I ended up while writing a c++ program to make a special loop entrance and to break out multiple loops. I had to declare the loop variable 'j, k' outside to have them declared before having jumped into the loop with goto, and used a fake do-loop to localize these.

So-many people say 'never use goto', and I do agree using unnecessary gotos will produce a not good program. However in this case, it is really hard for me to think of an alternative than using temporary switch variables and checking them on every loop entrance, which way I would think as very inefficient and harder to read.

Could you think of a nice way to make this part of my program better, or do you have a general suggestion?

Comment: Whole idea is to write code that does not require `goto` rather than simulate `goto` different way ie avoid it literally. It is difficult to say what you are trying to do in your code.

Comment: Start by changing your crazy initialization of the loop variables through `goto` with `first_time` and `skip` by simple assignment inside the first statement in the `for ()` part. Then all your spaghetti code will order nicely.

Comment: Does this try to find duplicates in a two-dimensional array?

Comment: @xiver77: Could you either explain what this code is trying to do or include the entire function in the question? It's very difficult (as you're seeing in the comments) to understand the goal of this code.

Comment: Create smaller sub functions. The code you show should be in a function and according to its result execute the `/* some code */` or not.

Comment: This code is **exactly** why we discourage `goto`. That said `goto` has perfectly respectable uses. This is not one of them.

Comment: @OP, With all said and done, it *is* a very good thing you're asking this question. It might be a better fit for codereview.SE, though.

Comment: One of the first things you learn when studying CS is that you *never* have to use `goto`, because `while` can replace all kinds of loops and also `if`.

Comment: `do{ ... } while(false)` could that just be replaced with the `{...}` part? is there any gain in having this wrapped in a loop that doesn't actually loop?

Comment: @YoungJohn, It allows you to use `break;` to get out of it without getting out of a larger section of code, but that doesn't happen here anyway.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that you need to do some work on your model of this concept.

Comment: `enum { WITH_ZERO }; ... return !WITH_ZERO;` combined with lambda functions, that's just great!!

Answer (score 8):

#### Short anwer

Break your code up into functions. You can replace these `goto`s with judicious use of helper methods and quick returns. Helper methods are a great way to manage the complexity of quadruply nested loops and snaking `goto`s. They will also reveal the underlying logic of your algorithm by giving names to the various moving parts.

#### Long answer:

As @MooingDuck deciphered in his comments, the only external effect of this code is to either exit the loop normally or exit it by jumping to the `next_num` label.

With that in mind, the first step would be to move the loop into a function that returns a `true` or `false` controlling whether or not to execute "some code".

```
if (should_execute_some_code()) {
    /*
     * some
     * code
     */
}

// starts the bigger loop outside
```

Inside the function, we'll convert any `goto next_num` line into `return true`, and otherwise `return false` if control falls off the bottom of the function.

```
bool should_execute_some_code()
{
    int j, k;
    if (num_copy_array[0][0] == num_copy_array[0][1]) {
        return true;
    }

    goto first_time;

    for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_LEN; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < NUM_LEN; k++) {
            goto skip;
        first_time:
            j = 0, k = 2;
        skip:
            for (int j_2 = 0; j_2 <= j; j_2++) {
                for (int k_2 = 0; k_2 <= NUM_LEN; k_2++) {
                    if (j_2 == j && k_2 == k) {
                        goto next_digit;
                    }
                    if (num_copy_array[j][k] == num_copy_array[j_2][k_2]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        next_digit:;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

That's a start. Now how can we get rid of the rest of the gotos? Let's tackle that `first_time` label. There's no need to jump inside the loop unconditionally. It's not pretty, but we can replace the jump with a conditional initialization for `k`. Set it to `2` on the first iteration and `0` thereafter. That lets us get rid of the `first_time` and `skip` labels.

```
bool should_execute_some_code()
{
    int j = 0, k = 2;

    if (num_copy_array[0][0] == num_copy_array[0][1]) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LEN; j++) {
        for (int k = (j == 0 ? 2 : 0); k < NUM_LEN; k++) {
            for (int j_2 = 0; j_2 <= j; j_2++) {
                for (int k_2 = 0; k_2 <= NUM_LEN; k_2++) {
                    if (j_2 == j && k_2 == k) {
                        goto next_digit;
                    }
                    if (num_copy_array[j][k] == num_copy_array[j_2][k_2]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        next_digit:;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Next there's the `next_digit` label. If `j == j_2` and `k == k_2` you want to stop the inner two loops. That could be controlled with a more selective loop condition instead of a `goto`.

```
bool should_execute_some_code()
{
    if (num_copy_array[0][0] == num_copy_array[0][1]) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LEN; j++) {
        for (int k = (j == 0 ? 2 : 0); k < NUM_LEN; k++) {
            for (int j_2 = 0; j_2 <= j; j_2++) {
                for (int k_2 = 0; k_2 <= NUM_LEN && !(j_2 == j && k_2 == k); k_2++) {
                    if (num_copy_array[j][k] == num_copy_array[j_2][k_2]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

At this point, it looks to me like you're checking if any entry in the two-dimensional array equals any other entry in the two-dimensional array. And you're careful to ignore checking the same cell against itself. Okay then. Let's rename the function now that we know what it does. Let's also break apart the four nested loops by introducing a second helper function.

```
bool has_duplicate_entry()
{
    if (num_copy_array[0][0] == num_copy_array[0][1]) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LEN; j++) {
        for (int k = (j == 0 ? 2 : 0); k < NUM_LEN; k++) {
            if (contains_entry(num_copy_array[j][k], j, k)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool contains_entry(int entry, int not_j, int not_k)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= not_j; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= NUM_LEN && !(j == not_j && k == not_k); k++) {
            if (num_copy_array[j][k] == entry) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: for (int k_2 = 0; k_2 <= NUM_LEN && !(j_2 == j && k_2 == k); k_2++) this line can only break one loop, I believe in this case it still works, but will have some unnecessary computations.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest something like (with better names):

```
bool bar(int j, int k)
{
    for(int j_2 = 0; j_2 <= j; j_2++) {
        for(int k_2 = 0; k_2 <= NUM_LEN; k_2++) {
            if(j_2 == j && k_2 == k) {
                return true;
            }
            if(num_copy_array[j][k] == num_copy_array[j_2][k_2]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool foo()
{
    if(num_copy_array[0][0] == num_copy_array[0][1]) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LEN; j++) {
        for(int k = (j == 0) ? 2 : 0; k < NUM_LEN; k++) {
            if (bar(j, k) == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void foobar()
{
    if (foo()) {
    /*
     * some
     * code
    */
    }
    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another check to your loops, such as:

```
for (i=0; i < x && !ready; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < y && !ready; j++)
    {
        // Now you can maintain the ready variable to finish...
        if (whatever)
            ready = true; // Or, ready = NULL Or ready > 0 etc (whatever suits your situation) 
    }
}
```

If you can break down your code into more functions so not requiring so many nested loops that may also help.

Comment: Personally, I find a `bool` variable being used to replace a `goto` for breaking out of a nested loop to be just as bad, if not worse.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a boolean - I'm suggesting an additional check to both loops. In some situations a boolean does make sense or can make it easier to read.

Comment: That's what I mean. `ready` is a boolean and its only purpose is to determine when to stop the outer loop via being set within the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

In *Elements of Programming*, Stepanov and McJones present a state machine that is elegantly coded, even with `goto`s.  And they mention that the obvious non-`goto` version isn't nearly as elegant.  Knuth spends a chapter of *Literate Programming* to argue for the occasional use of `goto`.  I'm no fan of `goto`, but I accept it has its uses.  However, I always try a non-`goto` version of any code.

In this case, I think you're trying to [simulate named loops](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/Idioms/Topics/07.SB.NamedLoops/html/text.html), but I don't think you need to.  For one, the outer `do` ... `while` loop looks an awful lot like a crippled function, that can only be called when some variables are in the right state.  You can (and, I argue, **should**) replace it with a function; and when you do, you'll notice that you no longer need `goto skip` or `first_time`.

I started trying to refactor the code, but without knowing what you actually want to do, I'm not able to do much.

Comment: The chapter of Knuth's *Literate Programming* is in effect an archived form of his paper *Structured programming with go to statements* dating back to 1974. He discussed several usages (and eliminations) of the **go to** statement.